Odd Google Analytics Traffic from Jeffersonville
Reviewing my city traffic for the last quarter I noticed an unusual traffic pattern from Jeffersonville (Note: we are in California):

Here are my observations.

Average engagement time: 0s
Traffic only goes to the homepage
View numbers vary by day which should exclude any automated scans/pings

Any ideas what this could be?
I could not find any logical traffic sources or others experiencing similar statistics
